# Google TV Pairing Protocol -- SSL Handshake Error with Go (golang)

Tags: go, google-tv

I'm writing a Go package for the Google TV Pairing Protocol. But I seem to be hitting a problem with the TLS handshake.

```
sock, err := tls.Dial("tcp", "10.8.0.1:9552", &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true})
```

That line gives me a handshake error. The exact error message is: `remote error: handshake failure`. If I try the same host/port via curl, it gives `curl: (35) error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3` alert handshake failure as well.

Any ideas? Is the Google TV expecting a client cert maybe? I haven't seen any references to the need for a client cert anywhere.

If anyone wants to help figure it out, here's the code:
https://github.com/dustywilson/go-polo

The README file has the easy code to check it out. You will have to know the IP address for your Google TV box since this doesn't use mDNS. If you (someone, anyone) run this and you get different results, let me know.

I've already gone through the Google TV Remote code at [google-tv-remote](http://code.google.com/p/google-tv-remote/). A more useful one is [google-tv-pairing-protocol](http://code.google.com/p/google-tv-pairing-protocol/) which is the equivalent Java/Android project to what I'm doing. Of course I've already poured over that code. I think it's a problem either with Go itself (unlikely), a problem with the Go TLS package not knowing how to read the Google TV's certificate (I know it was a problem a year ago), or a problem with my code (typically would be most likely, but I'm just not seeing it).

By the way, I'm testing this on a Logitech Revue and it has a self-signed SSL certificate.  It's not rooted or modified in any way.

My resulting code will be open source, of course.  Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Client certs are generated by the Java remote client at runtime, and stored for future use.  Check out the code at:

http://code.google.com/p/google-tv-remote/source/browse/src/com/google/android/apps/tvremote/KeyStoreManager.java

You might be running into an invalid cert.  According to the code, you need a specific CN.

/* Returns the name that should be used in a new certificate.
 * The format is: "CN=anymote/PRODUCT/DEVICE/MODEL/unique identifier"
 */

Comment: Are you saying that it expects me to send a client cert at handshake time?  If so, that would make sense and I should buy you a puppy for being awesome.  If not, let me know where I went wrong in my understanding of this message.

Comment: I haven't stepped through the entire process yet, but it looks like SSL is required during the initial pairing request, per: http://code.google.com/p/google-tv-remote/source/browse/src/com/google/android/apps/tvremote/PairingActivity.java#240

Comment: I'm flagging this as the answer for now.  I haven't verified it, but it seems useful.  In particular it seems that a client SSL cert is needed, which I didn't use.  If somehow that turns out to be not the case or someone comes along with a better or more complete answer, I'll switch it to them.  But I appreciate the input and hate to leave this in an unanswered state since it might be answered well enough, so ... here ya go.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you do need a client certificate.  The security of the pairing protocol relies on SSL mutual authentication: both sides present a cert, each side computes a value that is a function of both certs, and then that value is displayed by one and accepted as input by the other.  (source: I am the protocol's author :).